# a motivating proof that continuously differentiable complex function is infinitely differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

Why an analytic function is infinitely differentiable?

I know that analytic functions are not same as real differentiable function,it acts like a combitaion of rotation and translation,so they should have some interesting properties different from real differentiable function.But,the fact that they are infinitely differentiable is quite surprising for me.

So, I am looking for a more intuitive view, why they are infinitely differentiable?

Note:A complex function $f$ defined on a region $G\subset\mathbb{C}$ is said to be analytic if,  $f:G\to \mathbb{C}$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: there are two short answers - they satisfy an elliptic PDE ($\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=0$) and there is a general theorem that functions that satisfy elliptic pde's are smooth, or somewhat simpler they are representable by convolution with the Cauchy Kernel (so integrating the function multiplied by the Cauchy Kernel on a closed curve) which means that one can differentiate the kernel $1/(z-\zeta)$ in $z$ (integration being in $\zeta$) and get the derivatives of the function