# Simple explanation as to why complex functions are infinitely differentiable.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am seeking a simple explanation for why complex function, if they are differentiable, must be infinitely differentiable.

I have looked at other questions on this site, and discussion elsewhere, and can't any explanation that doesn't require university level mathematics and terminology.

---

EDIT 1 - Several comments have suggested similar questions ([eg](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640/why-are-differentiable-complex-functions-infinitely-differentiable)), but sadly the answers there require university level mathematics and terminology.

Comment: well, it's a very non-trivial result (btw note that the function is supposed to be differentiable on an entire open set; a single point is not enough), so you can't expect it to have a simple answer which can be completely dumbed down. The reason is Cauchy's integral formula: $f(z)=\int_{|w-a|=r}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,dw$. The ability to express the value of a complex-differentiable function via an integral over some curve gives rise to all sorts of wonderful results.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/820/568204) explains why complex-differentiable functions can be expected to have nicer local properties, but of course it is very far from obvious why this simple heuristic would imply the amazing result that once-complex differentiable on an open set implies analytic (hence infinitely differentiable).

Comment: @peek-a-boo As an aside, [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/63205/28209) has references to proofs that avoid integration, but it seems there is general agreement that they're harder.

Comment: @MarkS. thank you for the comment. I remember that comment made by Ahlfors when reading, but never bothered to look into it further and had forgotten about it till you mentioned it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are differentiable complex functions infinitely differentiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640/why-are-differentiable-complex-functions-infinitely-differentiable)

Comment: Also duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3697024

Comment: Thanks everyone for suggestion the other links .. sadly the answers there aren't "simple enough" as requested by this question.

Comment: If you're familiar with the fact discussed in most multivariable calculus courses that a vector field $\langle u, v \rangle$ on a simply connected (no holes) region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $v_x - u_y = 0$ is conservative, this fact implies that for $f$ holomorphic (with continuous derivatives) and $C$ as before, $\int_C f(z)dz = 0$. From which the Cauchy Integral formula for $f$ can be deduced. And this expression is infinitely differentiable.